# How to convert ArrayList to nullable integer array?

Tags: c#

I want to convert ArrayList data to int?[].

I tried the below but failed.
Does any body have an idea?

```
data.ToArray(typeof(int?)) as int?[]
(int?[])data.ToArray(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(int)))
(int?[])data.ToArray(Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(typeof(int?)))
(int?[])data.ToArray(typeof(int?))
```

Comment: what type of data in `data`?

Comment: `data.ToArray(typeof(Nullable<int>)) as int?[];` would have worked

Answer (score 4):

If your ArrayList contains only nullable ints then this is the way to go:

```
var result = data.Cast<int?>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 2):

This should do it:

```
res = data.Cast<int?>().ToArray();
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways: if you want to *throw exception* if any item in the `data` can't be cast to `int?`:

```
  var result = data
    .Cast<int?>()
    .ToArray();
```

Or (*lenient*): cast only those item that can be cast to `int?`:

```
  var result = data
    .OfType<int?>()
    .ToArray();
```

Comment: `.OfType<int?>()` will not include `null` values.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!!

```
   result = data.Cast<int?>().ToArray();
```